# How to handle blank line,junk line and \n while converting an input file to csv file

Tags: python-3.x

Below is the sample data in input file. I need to process this file and turn it into a csv file. With some help, I was able to convert it to csv file. However not fully converted to csv since I am not able to handle \n, junk line(2nd line) and blank line(4th line). Also, i need help to filter transaction_type i.e., avoid "rewrite" transaction_type

```
{"transaction_type": "new", "policynum": 4994949}  
44uu094u4  
{"transaction_type": "renewal", "policynum": 3848848,"reason": "Impressed with \n the Service"}  
  
{"transaction_type": "cancel", "policynum": 49494949, "cancel_table":[{"cancel_cd": "AU"}, {"cancel_cd": "AA"}]}
{"transaction_type": "rewrite", "policynum": 5634549}
```

Below is the code

```
import ast
import csv

with open('test_policy', 'r') as in_f, open('test_policy.csv', 'w') as out_f:
    data = in_f.readlines()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        out_f,
        fieldnames=[
            'transaction_type', 'policynum', 'cancel_cd','reason'],lineterminator='\n',
        extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in data:
        dict_row = ast.literal_eval(row)
        if 'cancel_table' in dict_row:
            cancel_table = dict_row['cancel_table']
            cancel_cd= []
            for cancel_row in cancel_table:
                cancel_cd.append(cancel_row['cancel_cd'])            
            dict_row['cancel_cd'] = ','.join(cancel_cd)
            
        writer.writerow(dict_row)
```

Below is my output not considering the junk line,blank line and transaction type "rewrite".

transaction_type,policynum,cancel_cd,reason
new,4994949,,
renewal,3848848,,"Impressed with
the Service"
cancel,49494949,"AU,AA",

## Expected output

transaction_type,policynum,cancel_cd,reason
new,4994949,,
renewal,3848848,,"Impressed with the Service"
cancel,49494949,"AU,AA",

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I try to fix them but I do not know how CSV file work, but my small knoll age will suggest you to run this code before to convert the file.

```py
txt = {"transaction_type": "renewal",
       "policynum": 3848848,
       "reason": "Impressed with \n the Service"}
newTxt = {}

for i,j in txt.items():
    # local var (temporar)
    lastX = ""
    correctJ = ""

    # check if in J is ascii white space "\n" and get it out
    if "\n" in f"b'{j}'":
        j = j.replace("\n", "")

    # for grammar purpose check if
    # J have at least one space
    if " " in str(j):
        # if yes check it closer (one by one)
        for x in ([j[y:y+1] for y in range(0, len(j), 1)]):
            # if 2 spaces are consecutive pass the last one
            if x == " " and lastX == " ":
                pass
            # if not update correctJ with new values
            else:
                correctJ += x
            # remember what was the last value checked
            lastX = x

        # at the end make J to be the correctJ (just in case J has not grammar errors)
        j = correctJ

    # add the corrections to a new dictionary
    newTxt[i]=j

# show the resoult
print(f"txt = {txt}\nnewTxt = {newTxt}")
```

Termina:

```
txt = {'transaction_type': 'renewal', 'policynum': 3848848, 'reason': 'Impressed with \n the Service'}
newTxt = {'transaction_type': 'renewal', 'policynum': 3848848, 'reason': 'Impressed with the Service'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```